# Hibernate Batch Insert slows down other inserts afterwards

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, batch-processing

I am using `Hibernate 5.2.5.Final` and the following code for a batch insert of a few thousand bookings where the budget of each booking is the same and already existed in the DB before the insert:

```
public List<Long> batchInsertBookings(List<Booking> bookings, String resource) {
  List<Long> generatedIds = new ArrayList<>();
  router.setDataSource(resource);

  try (StatelessSession statelessSession = em.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession()) {
    int batchSize = 20;
    int numberOfEntities = bookings.size();
    UserTransaction userTransaction = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    userTransaction.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntities; i += batchSize) {
      int endIndex = Math.min(i + batchSize, numberOfEntities);
      List<Booking> batch = bookings.subList(i, endIndex);

      // Save the batch data
      for (Booking entity : batch) {
        statelessSession.insert(entity);
      }

      // Retrieve the generated IDs after flush
      List<Long> batchIds = batch.stream()
              .map(IObject::getId)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
      generatedIds.addAll(batchIds);
    }
      userTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug(e.getMessage(), getClass().getName());
    }
    return generatedIds;
  }
```

The insert-method is called in a new thread since the batch insert should happen in the background. The batch insert finishes after a reasonable amount of time and the bookings appear in the database. Other than that no further log entries regard the batch insert. After the batch insert one can still use the backend and the fetch operations for data are still comparably fast to before the insert. Although now, if I insert another entity (f.e. with an elementcollection or associations) the insert does not really finish. This regards the main thread as well as the new thread I created for the batch insert. An example for an insert I perform after the batch insert is the insert of a `ChangeLog`-entity with an element collection `diff` of strings, where there is a string for each of the thousands of bookings (which worked really fast before). Here the logs are as follows:

```
2023-07-26 14:51:49 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into diff_REV (REVTYPE, REVEND, REVEND_TSTMP, REV, changeLog_id, diff) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-07-26 14:51:49 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 1
2023-07-26 14:51:49 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select diff_rev0_.REV as REV1_57_, diff_rev0_.changeLog_id as changeL2_57_, diff_rev0_.diff as diff3_57_, diff_rev0_.REVTYPE as REVTYPE4_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND as REVEND5_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND_TSTMP as REVEND_T6_57_ from diff_REV diff_rev0_ where diff_rev0_.changeLog_id=? and diff_rev0_.diff=? and (diff_rev0_.REVEND is null) for update
2023-07-26 14:51:50 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into diff_REV (REVTYPE, REVEND, REVEND_TSTMP, REV, changeLog_id, diff) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-07-26 14:51:50 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 1
2023-07-26 14:51:50 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select diff_rev0_.REV as REV1_57_, diff_rev0_.changeLog_id as changeL2_57_, diff_rev0_.diff as diff3_57_, diff_rev0_.REVTYPE as REVTYPE4_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND as REVEND5_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND_TSTMP as REVEND_T6_57_ from diff_REV diff_rev0_ where diff_rev0_.changeLog_id=? and diff_rev0_.diff=? and (diff_rev0_.REVEND is null) for update
2023-07-26 14:51:51 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into diff_REV (REVTYPE, REVEND, REVEND_TSTMP, REV, changeLog_id, diff) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-07-26 14:51:51 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 1
2023-07-26 14:51:51 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select diff_rev0_.REV as REV1_57_, diff_rev0_.changeLog_id as changeL2_57_, diff_rev0_.diff as diff3_57_, diff_rev0_.REVTYPE as REVTYPE4_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND as REVEND5_57_, diff_rev0_.REVEND_TSTMP as REVEND_T6_57_ from diff_REV diff_rev0_ where diff_rev0_.changeLog_id=? and diff_rev0_.diff=? and (diff_rev0_.REVEND is null) for update
```

where we can see that for each string element in the element collection it takes 1 second to persist, which is definetly not normal, since if I dont do the batch insert and still persist such an entity it persists the full entity in a short time.

It is worth noticing that my Booking entity is associated to a lot of other enties (where for example `Account` has a good amount of other associations). The most nested are:

```
1 Account   (account)      <->  (mainBudget) Budget 0..1
0..1 Budget (parentBudget) <->  (subBudget) Budget *
1 Budget (budget) <-> (bookings) Booking *
```

An example for a `OneToMany`- and a `ManyToOne`-mapping for the associations looks like this:

In `Booking.java`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional= false)
@JoinColumn(name="budget_id")
@BatchSize(size = 50)
private Budget budget;
```

In `Budget.java`:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Booking.class, mappedBy = "budget")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Booking> booking;
```

What I noticed is that if I batch insert an entity which has no associations the insert after the batch inserts seem to work. I don't understand why this problem occurs and neither in the performance nor in the query logs I can find why. The query log only shows the queries which are to expect - i.e. batch inserts for the bookings and then after that the ChangeLog inserting as shown above.

What I tried so far:

1. I added the `@BatchSize`-annotations to all associations since it
   should be a [solution for the N+1 queries problem](https://hackernoon.com/3-ways-to-deal-with-hibernate-n1-problem) if it occurs
   in my case.
2. I added connection pooling (as can be seen in my `persistence.xml` below)
3. I used different methods to batch insert. The one I posted here is using a stateless sessions. I also tried using mehtod with a normal session with a custom transaction and another one with `@Transactional` and the `EntityManager` doing all the session work and getting flushed and cleared, or just flushed, after each batch.
4. I rebuilt the booking entity without the nested associations above (with just a simple one), which is how I found out, that it works faster then.
5. I fully fetched the bookings before inserting them (in case lazy loading is the issue), although I did not unproxy the accounts, since they are always subclasses and there is some problem with unproxying them and then reassigning them to the entity. It is also notable that if I don't load the level 1 associations for the booking before the insert I get a `LazyInitializationException`.
6. I commented out the `ChangeLog` persisting and let the new thread finish, although later the same problem with inserting also occurs in the main thread of the application.
7. I did everything without the ConnectionPooling at first, neither way it worked.
8. I removed all `Cascading`, but it should and did not matter since the budget entity for the booking already existed in the database before the insert.

My `persistence.xml` for batch inserting and connection pooling looks like this:

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="20"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="admin"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="pass"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="10"/>
```

and I log the following (if you have better ways of logging more relevant data please also let me know):

```
  <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="info"/>
```

Why could this happen?

Information for answer from @Rick James:

Those are the SQL Queries for one batch of bookings.

```
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for updatePlain
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?Plain
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)

... 17*3 more of the same rows here (i.e. one batch of 20 selects, updates and inserts)

2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for updatePlain
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?Plain
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-27 11:24:05 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 20
```

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE Booking` statement gives the following output. It is to note here, that there are different types of bookings (depending on the `DTYPE`) with different type of attributes. I renamed all the irrelevant attributes to `someAttributeX`. I.e. the entities that I am trying to persist which are referred to here as `PlainBooking` do not have these attributes.

```
'Booking', 'CREATE TABLE `Booking` (
`DTYPE` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
`id` bigint NOT NULL,
`changeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`moneyValue` bigint NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`isActive` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`debitor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute1` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute2` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute3` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`project` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute4` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` int DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute6` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`dateOfCompensation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`receiptDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`area` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`originalMoneyValue` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`dateOfBooking` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`manualChanges` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`recorder` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`dateOfRecording` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`yearOfBusiness` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`targetDiscount` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`costType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`creditor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`discount` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`tax` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`stkz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`cancelationNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`paymentReason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute7` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute8` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute9` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute10` int DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute11` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute12` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute13` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`someOtherAttribute14` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`budget_id` bigint NOT NULL,
`someOtherAssociation_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`reason_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK2acd5rbfcfpxoy64in0keam4q` (`budget_id`),
KEY `FKm5a1xte805xlbr4t36glj1mq2` (`someOtherAssociation_id`),
KEY `FKlj3hrmasc3m12pyt2k9sqie5j` (`reason_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK2acd5rbfcfpxoy64in0keam4q` FOREIGN KEY (`budget_id`) REFERENCES `Budget` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FKlj3hrmasc3m12pyt2k9sqie5j` FOREIGN KEY (`reason_id`) REFERENCES `Reason` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FKm5a1xte805xlbr4t36glj1mq2` FOREIGN KEY (`someOtherAssociation_id`) REFERENCES `SomeOtherAssociation` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

A single insert:

```
2023-07-29 14:48:44 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking_REV (REVTYPE, REVEND, REVEND_TSTMP, changeDate, changeDate_MOD, moneyValue, moneyValue_MOD, text, text_MOD, date, date_MOD, isActive, isActive_MOD, budget_id, budget_MOD, labels_MOD, dateOfCompensation, dateOfCompensation_MOD, type, type_MOD, receiptDate, receiptDate_MOD, area, area_MOD, originalMoneyValue, originalMoneyValue_MOD, dateOfBooking, dateOfBooking_MOD, manualChanges, manualChanges_MOD, recorder, recorder_MOD, dateOfRecording, dateOfRecording_MOD, yearOfBusiness, yearOfBusiness_MOD, targetDiscount, targetDiscount_MOD, costType, costType_MOD, creditor, creditor_MOD, project, creditor_MOD, reference, reference_MOD, discount, discount_MOD, status, status_MOD, tax, tax_MOD, stkz, stkz_MOD, cancelationNumber, cancelationNumber_MOD, paymentReason, paymentReason_MOD, orderNumber_MOD, reason_id, reason_MOD, receiptNumbers_MOD, accountString_MOD, DTYPE, id, REV) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?, ?)
```

Logging `org.hibernate` on `DEBUG` level for batch insert:

```
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@243dfe80]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
... 19*3 more of the same lines
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 20
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl Hibernate RegisteredSynchronization successfully registered with JTA platform
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG]org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction suspended [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JtaIsolationDelegate Surrounding JTA transaction resumed [org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl@64f0214a]
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl Reusing batch statement
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] org.hibernate.SQL insert into Booking (changeDate, moneyValue, text, budget_id, date, isActive, dateOfCompensation, reason_id, type, receiptDate, area, originalMoneyValue, dateOfBooking, manualChanges, recorder, dateOfRecording, yearOfBusiness, targetDiscount, costType, creditor, project, reference, discount, status, tax, stkz, cancelationNumber, paymentReason, DTYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PlainBooking', ?)
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.b.i.BatchingBatch Executing batch size: 6
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
2023-07-30 00:49:29 [DEBUG] o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
```

Comment: Is `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If not, how do you set the value?

Comment: @RickJames I use `@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
`. I am aware that the `IDENTITY` does not work with batch inserts.

Comment: MySQL is happy to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on batches.  But it pre-allocates all the new ids before starting to do the inserts.  So, if any row fails to be inserted (or the whole batch fails), some id(s) are "burned".  This is surprising to users, but "not-a-bug".

Comment: @RickJames Ah ok, I see. The thing is that after the batch insert the database shows all the booking entries that should be inserted, which means that everything "works correct". Its just that other inserts afterwards are really slow

Comment: Explain "other inserts are slow" -- Inserts into the same table at the "same" time"?  Into other tables?  With big, complex, Selects also going on in the background?  Deleting rows at the "same time"?  Other?

Comment: Simple inserts into any table (not using native queries but the entity manager) after the batch insert. The batch insert fully finishes. At least the entities are in the database and the queries appear in the log. Something from the batch insert seems to slow other inserts afterwards. Thats the only problem I have at all

Comment: "update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?" -- Is that bumping up by 1 or by 20?

Comment: There are 20 of those. One for each insert statement

Comment: But it seems to _triple_ the number of statements relative to using `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Also that 3-step operation should be inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading is likely to be counter-productive because of needing multiple connections.  ("Connection pooling" addresses a different issue.)

A batch should be between 100 and 1000 items.  More than that gets into "diminishing returns" and may encounter other things (big buffers, etc) that may slow it down.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample of the batched query.

**More**

47 columns is a lot.  Consider breaking out things like "booking" and its associated columns; discount/cost/credit/etc info; some of the "attributes"; clumps of things that are often NULL; etc.

"the budget of each booking is the same" -- sounds like this is an excellent case for breaking the booking stuff into another table.

12 columns are `BIGINT` (8 bytes each); probably none need to be any bigger than `INT` (4 bytes, max +/-2 billion).  This is only a small issue, but shrinking the data *may* help avoid the conflicts.

Let's see a sample `INSERT`.  (You can anonymize any sensitive data.)

Comment: I updated the question with the information you requested. 

Regarding multithreading: The reason I tried multithreading is, that the insert was so slow that it blocked the main thread and at some point timed out and the transaction rolled back. Is there some other way to avoid both?

When you say batch, are you referring to the total amount of bookings to persist in one transaction? The insert batch size to the database is 20 and there are a few thousand bookings to persist. Although I tried calling my batchInsert method on 1000 bookings at a time and it behaved the same way as before.

Comment: "batch" -- Multiple rows in a single `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @lasbr - and I added More.

Comment: So the  batch size  is set to 20. The data structure existed a long time. Only with the mass insert of bookings this problem arose. I can't change the data structure. Inserting a small amount of bookings at a time works fine. Before I did the mass insert in a new thread without batch inserting, but the reason I switched to batch inserting is the `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException` which batch inserting apparently is a solution to. What do you mean by a sample `INSERT`? Actual values for the variables?

Comment: By "simple", I mean 1 row at a time.  Roughly speaking, an `INSERT` has 10 units of time overhead.  Inserting a batch of 20 rows will take about 30 units of time (1.5 per row).

Comment: I also added a single insert at the end of the question

Comment: That looks like a singe row being inserted by one `INSERT`; no batching.  If you do 1000 of those from one client, it will take a few seconds and may or may not interfere with other clients also doing Inserts.

Comment: I thought you wanted to see a one line insert. I put a sample batch insert in the question, or is it something else you mean?

Comment: I'm hoping to see the generated SQL for a sample "batch".  That may include `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`; I am not fluent in "hibernate".

Comment: I could not really get the queries but I added some more logs to the question. It gives a little more insight than the ones I added before.

Comment: I just found out that when I add an entity with a collection of a few thousand strings after the batch insert, it shows `o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 3078 objects` in the logs after every element that is inserted into the element collection. The number of objects increases by 1 after every insert into the collection

Comment: Although the increasing number of objects i talked about in my last comment seems to be the number of managed elements increasing with each item added to the collection. The speed at which it happens is although very slow